# User profile accounts not being removed after filter and full sync

Tags: user-profile-service

Trying to get rid of some accounts, and the filter IS working in FIM..showing 160+ deletes.  But when I perform a search in SharePoint, these accounts still show up.  Any thoughts on what other rocks we may need to turn over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform full profile sync n in some cases multiple incremental run required. Also run search crawl as well to update the index...did you see the profile from central admin page?

Comment: It apparently fixed itself, so Im going with running additional incrementals.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to kick off the "User Profile Service - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" timer job. I think it runs hourly by default.